# Git merge commit dissapeared - cannot revert

Tags: git, azure-devops

We have a few branches, mainly main -> develop -> team-branch ->feature-branches. After merging our features together, develop to team-branch and then team-branch to develop we realized that we have to reverse this merge, but there is no merge commit for that, only for merge between my feature branch and team branch.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWNk0.png)

here is ss from azure git history:

If i remember well i used commands:

```
git checkout feature/zad3_Filtering  
git merge feature_zad3_nowy ---- main team branch;  

git checkout feature/zad3_nowy   
git merge feature/zad3_Filtering  
git pull origin develop  

git checkout develop    
git pull  
git merge feature/zad3_nowy
```

Comment: It kind of looks like it was rebased instead of merged https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing

Answer (score 0):

As per the above commands you have merged code in below branches. 
feature/zad3_Filtering
feature/zad3_nowy
develop

And now you wanna revert the code of above branches to there previous commits. For this
you need to find the commit which the last commit before merge
You can find the commit by below command
**git log --pretty=format:"%h - %an, %ar : %s"**

Pic the commit id and revert the code to you last commit by below commands
**git revert last commit id**